# No module named 'scheduler.schedulers'

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Пытаюсь написать телеграм бота, при компиляции выдает такую ошибку:

```
line 15, in <module>
    from scheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scheduler.schedulers'
```

Все библиотеки установлены, вроде как все.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить модуль

```
$ pip install apscheduler
```

И поменять импорт на

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
```